# Regex doesn't find groups

Tags: java, regex

I need to return the strings that are betwee stars in the following string

```
String str = "/articles/0,7340,4464361,00.htm?=95.Food-11294.Pasta*20140122*12*";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\*(\\d+)\\*").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

I expect in return to get the following groups:
20140122 and 12

However, `*20140122*` is returned.

How can I return `20140122` and `12` (without the stars)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=\*)(\d+)(?=\*)
```

Try this.Grab the captures.Your regex `\\*(\\d+)\\*` eats up an `*`.so next string after first cannot be matched.So use `0 width assertions.`See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/vR4fY4/13

`\\*(\\d+)\\*`==>matches `*200002*` ..now the next string has no `*` for itself.String left is `12*`.So it cannot be matched.Lookaheads are 0 widht assertions so they do not consume `*`.

Comment: Thanks it works. I will accept it in 10 min. can you explain it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a capturing group . Lookbehinds and lookaheads are comes under the Look around category. [Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) are zero width assertions which won't capture any characters but only assert whether a match is possible or not.

```
String str = "/articles/0,7340,4464361,00.htm?=95.Food-11294.Pasta*20140122*12*";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\*)\\d+(?=\\*)").matcher(str);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<=\\*)` Asserts that the match must be preceded by a `*`.
- `\\d+` Matches one or more digits.
- `(?=\\*)` Asserts that the match must be followed by a `*`